# PhoneGap/Cordova - Not getting the "camera permission" prompts

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, camera, phonegap

I am using the PhoneGap Desktop emulator to test my app that just takes a picture using the device camera. **All works well in the PhoneGap app** on Android and iOS. I get the prompts before I take a picture asking to allow PhoneGap to have access to the camera. Then, all future camera requests work OK. As I would expect.

However, when I create the native apps, and run them on iOS/Android devices, they no longer prompt me for permission to use the camera, and on iOS it just crashes when I try to open the camera. On Android, it just does nothing when I trigger the camera.

I'm struggling to work out why it works using the PhoneGap App, but doesn't when I run it as a native App? Am I missing something?

I am creating the App structure, adding platforms/plugins etc. using the cordova CLI on my Ubuntu server. I am using the Adobe PhoneGap build servers (v7.0.1) to compile the native Apps. I was only using PhoneGap desktop to test this issue.

iOS device OS version = v11.0.3
Android device OS version = 7.0

**My config.xml file:**

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mycameraapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My Camera App</name>
    <description>
Test App
    </description>
    <author email="hello@mycameraapp.com" href="http://www.mycameraapp.com">
        My Camera App
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.3" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^3.0.0">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To take pictures from within the App" />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To take pictures from within the App" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

**The JavaScript that triggers the camera:**

```js
function upload_case_image(mode) {
 
 
 openCamera(mode);
 
}



function setOptions(srcType) {
 var options = {
  // Some common settings are 20, 50, and 100
  quality: localStorage.getItem('image_quality'), // Image quality is defined in the database
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  // In this app, dynamically set the picture source, Camera or photo gallery
  sourceType: srcType,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  allowEdit: false,
  correctOrientation: true  //Corrects Android orientation quirks
 }
 return options;
}


function openCamera(mode) {

 var srcType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
 var options = setOptions(srcType);
 

 navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {

  upload_image(mode, imageUri);

 }, function cameraError(error) {
  console.debug("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");

 }, options);
}
```

**My index.html is in the normal place within www, and references the corodva.js file:**

```html
    
<!-- Cordova -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've worked out where I was going wrong.

I was using Cordova, rather than the PhoneGap CLI. I installed Node.js on my PC, then installed PhoneGap (npm install -g phonegap@latest).

Then using command prompt I created the App using PhoneGap in Windows, instead of using Cordova on Ubunutu.

When I uploaded it to the Adobe build servers to build the PhoneGap App, it appears to work now.

Makes sense why I would encounter some difficulties.